# Move car at same speed

Tags: unity

I want to move car on each game play run with same speed. At present I was getting each time different velocity. I want to fix that.

Here is game play area on which I was moving car:

[image]

At present I was moving car in infinite motion without any kind of control. When it collide with wall, it will its direction based on collision calculation.

Here is my source code that I was using to move car:

```
void Start ()
 {
     direction = new Vector2 (Random.Range (-1f, 1f), Random.Range (-1f, 1f));
 }

 void FixedUpdate ()
 {

     float angle = Mathf.Atan2 (direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
     float targetRot = Mathf.LerpAngle (myRigidbody.rotation, (angle - 90f), 0.1f);
     myRigidbody.MoveRotation (targetRot);

     myRigidbody.velocity = direction * speed;
//        myRigidbody.MovePosition (myRigidbody.position + direction * Time.deltaTime * speed);

     Debug.Log("vel mag: " + myRigidbody.velocity.magnitude);
 }

 void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D other)
 {
     ContactPoint2D contact;
     contact = other.contacts [0];

//        direction = 2 * (Vector3.Dot(direction, Vector3.Normalize(contact.normal))) * Vector3.Normalize(contact.normal) - direction; //Following formula  v' = 2 * (v . n) * n - v

//        direction *= -1;// Dont know why I had to multiply by -1 but it's inversed otherwisae
     Vector2 reflectedVelocity = Vector2.Reflect(direction, contact.normal);   
     direction = reflectedVelocity;
 }
```

At present on each run of car, I was getting different velocity that I have checked via debug statement. So my target is to move car with same speed always.

Comment: Because your direction is a speed, and you set it to random. Try `direction = new Vector2 (Random.Range (-1f, 1f), Random.Range (-1f, 1f)).normalized;` (which will screw up if both x and y are 0),

Comment: Yes its just a initial direction giving each time different velocity magnitude during game play.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing your random direction with

```
float angle = Random.Range(0f, 2f * Mathf.PI);
direction = new Vector2(
                  Mathf.Cos(angle), 
                  Mathf.Sin(angle)
               );
```

This will ensure the direction always has unit length, avoiding the singularity where both x & y get a random value of 0. It also selects directions with uniform probability, compared to normalizing a random value in a square, which is biased toward the diagonals of the square.